# How to retrieve the version number of a specific file in AWS S3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a bucket with versioning enabled. When i upload a file with an existing key, a new version should be created. However, my problem is that I would like to store this current  version number locally as well. How can i retrieve it nicely?

I see that you can at least retrieve all versions of the same file, as well as retrieve a file with a specific version number. I was, though, unable to find any information of how to get the version number of a file I just uploaded. Is there any smart way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using TransferManager service to upload and download files, but this did not have much possibilities to "peek" on a file. However, it seems that the class AmazonS3.getObjectMetadata.getVersionId could do the trick.